# How can I insert a picture in a Super User question?

Tags: support, images

I am trying to insert a picture in a Super User question. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find out (more generally) about the formatting and content you can add to a post, click the `?` at the top right corner of the input text area when writing a post.

> [image]

A new bar with categories will appear. The buttons this help item applies to will jump up and down repeatedly when you click on a category, and extensive help on that topic appears.

> [image]

Comment: I just had to post this. I never knew this existed until I was on the site as a new user and looking at the question form, where this help bar is shown by default.

Answer (score 13):

[image: clickme!]

Comment: There's also a full FAQ post available on MSO - [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: True. I couldn't pass up the chance for a *meta* answer, by uploading an image of the question as the answer ;)

Comment: How did you get that image into your question? ;) :P